# Measurability condition of point processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, point-processes

Let $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $(S, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space. Let $S^{\infty}$ be the collection of countable subsets of $S$. Assume that $\left\{x\right\} \in \Sigma$ for every $x \in S$. By a point process on $(S, \Sigma)$ we mean any random countable subset of $S$.

In my understanding, a random countable subset $X$ on $(S, \Sigma)$ is a random variable
$$X: \Omega \rightarrow S^{\infty}.$$
But as a random variable, it should be a measurable function. However, it is unclear to me, with respect to what sigma algebra? I.e., what is the sigma algebra $S^{\infty}$ is equipped with?

Comment: Let's simplify to assume "countable" means "countably infinite." Then $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, ...\}$ is just a sequence of random elements $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow S$ that are measurable with respect to the input space $(\Omega, F)$ and the output space $(S, \Sigma)$. You can define an object $X=(X_1, X_2, ...)$ with the product space if you want. Now if you want to allow finite sets you can have a random variable $N\in\{-1, 0, 1, 2, ...\}$ and $N=-1$ means we consider the infinite list $(X_1, X_2, ...)$, $N=0$ means we consider no points in $S$, while $N>0$ means we consider $(X_1, ..., X_N)$.

Comment: PS: I prefer to call a "random variable" a measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ assuming the output space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$; and a "random element" a measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow S$ for some given output space $(S, \Sigma)$.

Comment: @Michael So you would equip $S^{\infty}$ with a product sigma algebra?

Comment: No, more work would need to be done to determine what aspect of $S^{\infty}$ you want to capture, if structure $(N,X)$ is fine or if you want an unordered subset structure. I think it is simpler to work directly with the random variable $N$ and the sequence of random elements $(X_1, X_2, X_3, ...)$. Then, if you want to know the probability that $N=-1$ and there are 12 points in some particular subset $B \subseteq S$, that is $$P\left[\{N=-1\}\cap \left\{12=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1_{\{X_i \in B\}} \right\}\right]$$ and we note that $1_{\{X_i\in B\}}$ is a Bernoulli random variable for each $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most useful (and certainly the most common) way to proceed is as follows. Define a $\sigma$-field $\mathscr S$ of subsets of $S^\infty$ to be that generated by subsets of $S^\infty$ of the form $\{H\in S^\infty: \#(H\cap B) =n\}$, for $B\in\Sigma$ and $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,\infty\}$. (Here $\#(C)$ denotes the cardinality of $C$.) With this definition of $\mathscr S$, a map $X:\Omega\to S^\infty$ is a random countable set (i.e., a random element of $S^\infty$) if and only if
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega: \#(X(\omega)\cap B) =n\}\in\mathcal F,
$$
for all $B\in\Sigma$ and all $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,\infty\}$.

Under minimal conditions on $(S,\Sigma)$, the points of $X$ can be enumerated in a measurable way: There is a sequence of $S$-valued random variables, $\xi_1, \xi_2,\ldots$ and an $\{0,1,2,\ldots,\infty\}$-valued random variable $N$ (all defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$) such that
$$
\#(X(\omega)\cap B) =\sum_{n=1}^{N(\omega)}1_B(\xi_n(\omega)),
$$
for all $B\in\Sigma$ and all $\omega\in\Omega$. ($N$ is there to account for the possibility that $X(\omega)$ is a finite set for some $\omega$s.)

Answer (score 1):

More detail on my comments: It depends on what aspect of "the set of all countable subsets of $S$" you want to capture. Note that this set is distinct from the simpler set
$$ S^{\mathbb{N}} = \{(s_1, s_2, s_3, ...): s_i \in S \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
where $\mathbb{N}=\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ is the set of natural numbers. The set $S^{\mathbb{N}}$ is simpler because it has the structure of a countably infinite ordered list, whereas "the set of all countable subsets of $S$" could contain finite sets and does not necessarily order the elements of the sets.

---

If you really want to define a random element that specifies all points, you could do this:

Define a new element called "null" that is distinct from all elements of $S$. Then define:
$$S' = S \cup \{null\}$$
and define $\Sigma'$ as the set of all subsets of $S'$ of the form $A$ or $A \cup \{null\}$ for some $A \in \Sigma$. You can show that $\Sigma'$ is indeed a sigma algebra on $S'$.

Now for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ define random elements $$X_i:\Omega\rightarrow S'$$
that are measurable with respect to the input space $(\Omega, F)$ and the output space $(S', \Sigma')$. Then $(X_1, X_2, X_3, ...)$ specifies the countable collection of points in $S$, and if $X_i=null$ then there is no point included for index $i$. This allows having a finite set of points, meaning that $X_i=null$ for all but finitely many $i$.

Then you can define
$$X=(X_1, X_2, X_3, ...)$$
which can either be viewed as a sequence of random elements, or can be viewed as a random element itself:
$$X:\Omega\rightarrow (S')^{\mathbb{N}}$$
equipped with the product sigma algebra
$$ \otimes_{i=1}^{\infty} \Sigma' = \Sigma' \otimes \Sigma' \otimes \Sigma'...$$
which is the sigma algebra generated by all sets of the form
$$ A_1 \times A_2  \times ... \times A_n \times S' \times S' \times S' ...$$
for some positive integer $n$ and some sets $A_i\in \Sigma'$ for $i \in\{1, ..., n\}$.